# JAXB doesn't report about illegal element duplicate

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

Suppose I have an annotated Java class:

```java
@XmlRootElement
class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

Instances of that class should be created from an XML document. But sometimes XML record does not match well to my POJOs. For example, it may has multiple `<name>` tags:

```xml
<person>
  <name>Dr. Jekyll</name>
  <name>Mr. Hyde</name>
  <age>35</age>
</person>
```

In such cases I expect to get an error message from unmarshaller. But it actually just quietly re-initializes the property twice. Is there a way to make JAXB notify me about those errors? (Something like `VerificationErrorHandler` would be a perfect solution. Throwing an exception from the property setter looks too boiler-platy for me)

**UPD.** My JAXB setup contains no surprise:

```java
var jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
var jaxbDecoder = jaxb.createUnmarshaller();
var errorLog = new ArrayList<ValidationEvent>();
jaxbDecoder.setEventHandler(e -> errorLog.add(e));
// Now unmarshal:
var p = (Person) jaxbDecoder.unmarshal(xml);
```

After that, `errorLog` is empty despite my XML document is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Share your "unmarshalling details" ...https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#unmarshalling-unmarshalling-is-not-working-help

Comment: ..then we can also "try to install `ValidationEventHandler` on the unmarshaller" ..and check JAXBContext;)

Comment: @xerx593 I did, and this doesn't helped (see post update). And also I have no complete XSD schema of a document to validate against, so the next tip from the user guide ("Make sure your instance document is valid") is not relevant to my case.

Comment: Without an XSD there no such "errors" as long as the XML is well formed so JAXB can't see multiple elements as an error.